# Как сделать чтобы переходя по url отображалась вся страница а не только контент

Tags: jquery, ajax

Вообщем есть код. Выполняет переход по ссылке с помощью ajax без обновления страницы. Но если скопировать url и вставить в новом окне то отобразиться только содержимое контента. Как сделать чтобы отобразилась вся страница

```
$('.menu__link').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: url + '?ajax=1',
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });

    if(url != window.location){
        window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
    }

    return false;
});
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: location.pathname + '?ajax=1',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Через якоря это делается (hash). При переходе по ссылке меняете `location.hash`. Соответственно при посещении страницы считываете hash и загружаете контент

Comment: Меня интересует переход на другую страницу следующим образом ("/name-page.html")

Answer (score 0):

Браузер отображает то, что дает ему сервер. Сервер отдает по url "лишь контент" - браузер его и отображает.

Могу предположить, что параметр "ajax" указывает серверу, что нужно вернуть: "лишь контент" или страницу целиком.

Попробуйте в новом окне указать ссылку с ajax=0 (если серверная часть "не ваша"). Ну или сделайте так, чтобы сервер возвращал полную страницу при обычном (не ajax) запросе.

Определить, что на сервер пршел ajax-запрос можно по наличию HTTP-заголовка **X-Requested-With**